# Грамотно ли написано предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, частица-не

Но не смотря ни на что меня не покидала мысль о работе онлайн.

Comment: Что за 99?.....

Answer (score 2):

**Но, несмотря ни на что, меня не покидала мысль о работе онлайн.**

[**Несмотря ни на что**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_860&v=full) ("несмотря" — слитно) в этом предложении выступает в роли обстоятельственного оборота, поэтому его нужно выделить запятыми.

Вот похожие предложения.
*Но, несмотря ни на что, меня не покидала мысль о новом директоре детдома...* (А. Шадрин); *Но, несмотря ни на что, одна мысль не покидала меня: «Я должен обстенить кливер»* (Д. Лондон).

[Здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20) можно посмотреть предложения с "несмотря ни на что" — с обособлением и без него.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:

Но, несмотря ни на что, меня не покидала мысль о работе онлайн.

`Несмотря` - вместе пишется.